# Angularjs - $resource as a service, issue with multiple urls

Tags: angularjs

I have this service :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('Consultant', Consultant);

    Consultant.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];

    function Consultant ($resource, DateUtils) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/consultants/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT',
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    return angular.toJson(data);
                },
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'save': {
                method: 'POST',
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    return angular.toJson(data);
                },
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

What if I want to add the url `api/consultantscustom/:id` (with its query/get/update methods) to this service?
As it seems that this file can contain only one factory, is there a way to  do that or do I need to create another file with a new factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am totally misunderstanding what you are asking, but you can have as many factories in one file as you like (or as seems useful):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
      .factory('Consultant', Consultant)
      .factory('Custom', Custom);

    Consultant.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];
    Custom.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function Consultant ($resource, DateUtils) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/consultants/:id';
        ...
    }

    function Custom ($resource) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/consultantscustom/:id';
        ...
    }
```

---

Or, if you want to re-use the same factory to access different URLs, you could add methods to set the URL and then re-use the call to the generic resource.

```
function Consultant ($resource, DateUtils) {

  function consultants () {
    _call_resource('api/consultants/:id');
  }
  function custom () {
    _call_resource('api/consultantscustom/:id');
  }

  function _call_resource (resourceUrl) {
    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
      ...
    }
  }

  this.consultants = consultants;
  this.custom = custom;
  return this;
}
```